# How to combine different AddHandler?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, universal-code

Yesterday, I was asking the [Question about making .htaccess file "universal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075885/how-to-create-universal-htaccess-file) so that I can use it on different servers.
Today, I found that the problem is arrising only because of 1 line,
"AddHandler"

On 1 server It's working by adding at the top

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .html
```

While on another server It's working by using,

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

But when I combine both lines, It works only on single server. Isn't it possible to combine different "AddHandler" to work on all servers?

Comment: Why are you forcing .html files to be processed by the PHP engine?

Comment: I'm using various php codes in html files. I want html files treated as php, so I've added those lines to parse html files as PHP